# Chrome Manifest V3 Background Fetch

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I wish to download large files in the background from an external source
I tried following the [Chrome Developers article](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/background-fetch/), but it's not directly compatible with extensions, i.e. `navigator.serviceWorker` is `undefined`

Comment: Use `registration.backgroundFetch` inside service worker to access the API directly.

Comment: How do I use it in practice? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Just call it directly e.g. registration.backgroundFetch.fetch('foo', ......)

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'BackgroundFetchManager': No active registration available on the ServiceWorkerRegistration.`

Comment: Works for me. I guess you've encountered the bug in Chrome that breaks SW registration. Try uninstalling the extension, then install it again. ManifestV3 is still bugged as hell.

Comment: Exception does not occur when fetch is called from pupup. However, it becomes failureReason:"fetch-error".
The fetch event has fired.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/developer.chrome.com/issues/2001) is not very encouraging

Comment: I was able to progress by using [onstatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker/statechange_event), but now I can't figure out how to get an actual URL out of the `.fetch`

Comment: [This example](https://github.com/WICG/background-fetch#downloading-a-movie) is confusing me

Answer (score -1):

Service workers don't work exactly the same in extensions as they do on the web. First, you [register them in the manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/#manifest) rather than on `navigator`.

I believe background fetch works within an extension service worker. If it doesn't, you can still call [global `fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) to download the files.

Comment: The problem with using a plain `fetch` is that a Service Worker's lifespan is up to 5 minutes. However, I did find a [solution](https://github.dev/guest271314/persistent-serviceworker)